No printf() output from .t program under "make test" for a Perl module
Perl 5.36 on Cygwin under Windows-11 (Home):
I decided to make clear what part of my test is being run so I added a printf() call to the .t program and ran make test.  The test passes but I get no output on the terminal from the printf. I have tried redirecting 1>&2 and 2>&1 (Logical act of desperation. ;-)
This is not desperately important since the test did pass.  But I would like to watch the progress of each component of the test.
Any ideas out there?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your test program needs to output proper TAP output.
With Test::More, you want to use note or diag instead of printf.
note text is only shown when verbose output is requested.
diag text is always shown.

As @ikegami noted (heh) and as you can read in Test::More's "Diagnostics" section.
Often I'm running a single test file, so instead of make test, which interprets (and hides) much of the output, I can see everything. Remember that you also have to tell perl where to find the libraries since you aren't letting make test do that for you:
% perl -Ilib t/some_test.t
... all of the output ...

In a test, sometimes I'm lazy while I'm debugging stuff and just output to STDERR (and this works in make test too):
printf {STDERR} $template, @args;

Some functions already show you what it wanted and what you had when if fails:
is $this, $that, 'this is that';

Other times it's easier to handle that yourself. If the test function fails, it returns false and you can use a short-circuit, low-precedence or to trigger a diag where you can design your own error message:
ok some_complicated_test(), "complicated test passes" 
    or diag( sprintf ... );



Brian, that worked for me. But I also found explain, an equivalent to Data::Dumper. Following that link now.  I would not have known what to search for.

You can test using prove and add the -v flag, then, writing to STDOUT and STDERR will show up.
You'd run your test like:
prove -v mytest.t

or to run an entire test-suite:
prove -rv t/

(-r lets prove recurse into sub directories)

Rawley and especially Brian,
I have tried your methods and leaned some good stuff from y'all.  Note that I had to export PERL5LIB=../lib if I wanted to prove one file within the t directory.
That aside, the answer was in the Makefile itself, wherein I noticed the code testing for a parameter "TEST_VERBOSE". The make test command I needed to use to see printf output was:
make test TEST_VERBOSE=1 and voila, I see my very verbose printf output.
Thank you all!
-- Jacob S
